# What's the relationship between δ and d/dt?

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations

I understand how

$$m\int \frac{d\mathbf{v}}{dt} \cdot \mathbf{v} dt = \frac{m}{2}\int \frac{d}{dt}(\mathbf{v}^2)dt$$

But how was the leap below made?

[Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLBID.png)

Wouldn't that require δv to equal $\frac{dv}{dt}$? How can that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of calculus of variations, $\delta$ can be interpreted as a directional derivative (of a function, typically *of* a function — so calculus of variations texts often refer to this as a functional) in an arbitrary direction (which is again a function). The heuristic your book is using is this: If you look at the variation of $F(f)$ in the direction of $g$, you are taking
$$\delta_g F(f) = \frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0}F(f+tg),$$
quite in analogy with directional derivatives in calculus, where you have
$$D_v f(p) = \frac d{dt}\Big|_{t=0} f(p+tv).$$
So the usual sum and product rules (and so forth) hold nicely.

This $t$ has nothing to do with the $t$ appearing in your time integrals.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you for the help. I was under the impression that the book was assuming that δv and $\frac{dv}{dt}$ were _the same thing_, while it was only in fact assuming that they _obey the same rules_, as you have elegantly explained above.

Comment: Can you recommend a book where I can read more about your explanation?

Comment: I don't have any of the standard books to check details for you, but there are Dover books by Weinstock and Gelfand/Fomin that are pretty well-known. I'm sure there are on-line sources, too, but I don't know them at all.